# How to remove braces [] from JSON Array data output?

Tags: android, json, android-volley

> My JSON structure is simple :

```
 "categories": [2],
```

> I am succesfull in getting this output on my Android studio code as :

```
  JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("categories");
  Log.e("CAT ID", String.valueOf(jsonArray));
```

> `Output` is :

```
E/CAT ID: [2]  //and other IDS respectively
```

> My question is how can I remove the braces and just get the Integer values?

Answer (score 3):

You can call  get() to get array value.

```
//If array contains only one value use get(0)

    JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("categories");
    
    jsonArray.get(0);

//If Array contains more value use for() loop

for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length;i++){
      jsonArray.get(i);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

jsut use below code :

```
String.valueOf(jsonArray)
    .replace("[","")
    .replace("]","")
```

or

```
jsonArray.toString()
    .replace("[","")
    .replace("]","")
```